# Meaning of a symbol in an orchestral score

Tags: notation

What does '+' mean in an orchestral score? This was an examination question in a music theory exam and I have been unable to find out the meaning

Comment: In _what context_?

Comment: Context! Please.

Answer (score 2):

Above a note it could mean 'stopped' for a French Horn. 'Closed' or 'damped' for a hi-hat or crush cymbal. For a stringed instrument it means a left hand pizzicato.  In a chord symbol it means the basic triad has an augmented 5th, as in 'C7+'.

Did the theory paper give no further context?